# Is there any way of detecting an automatic reload in flask's debug mode?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app where I'd like to execute some code on the *first* time the app is run, not on the automatic reloads triggered by the debug mode. Is there any way of detecting when a reload is triggered so that I can do this?

To give an example, I might want to open a web browser every time I run the app from sublime text, but not when I subsequently edit the files, like so:

```
import webbrowser
if __name__ == '__main__':
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:5000')
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set an environment variable.

```
import os
if 'WERKZEUG_LOADED' in os.environ:
    print 'Reloading...'
else:
    print 'Starting...'
    os.environ['WERKZEUG_LOADED']='TRUE'
```

I still don't know how to persist a reference that survives the reloading, though.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Flask-Script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to kick off a process before you start your server? Something like this (cribbed from their documentation and edited slightly):

```
# run_devserver.py

import webbrowser
from flask.ext.script import Manager

from myapp import app

manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:5000')
    manager.run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Flask app where it's not really practical to change the DEBUG flag or disable reloading, and the app is spun up in a more complex way than just `flask run`.

@osa's solution didn't work for me with flask debug on, because it doesn't have enough finesse to pick out the werkzeug watcher process from the worker process that gets reloaded.

I have this code in my main package's `__init__.py` (the package that defines the flask app). This code is run by another small module which has `from <the_package_name> import app` followed by `app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)`. Therefore this code is executed before the app starts.

```
import ptvsd
import os
my_pid = os.getpid()
if os.environ.get('PPID') == str(os.getppid()):
    logger.debug('Reloading...')
    logger.debug(f"Current process ID: {my_pid}")
    try:
        port = 5678
        ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', port))
        logger.debug(f'========================== PTVSD waiting on port {port} ==========================')
        # ptvsd.wait_for_attach()   # Not necessary for my app; YMMV
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.debug(f'PTVSD raised {ex}')
else:
    logger.debug('Starting...')
    os.environ['PPID'] = str(my_pid)
    logger.debug(f"First process ID: {my_pid}")
```

NB: note the difference between `os.getpid()` and `os.getppid()` (the latter gets the parent process's ID).

I can attach at any point and it works great, even if the app has reloaded already before I attach. I can detach and re-attach. The debugger survives a reload.